# Problem with add data to mySql with String.format in Java

Tags: java, mysql, string, format, truncate

I have problem when i try to add data to mySql Table with String.format.

MySql table:

```
CREATE TABLE Product (
Product_id int AUTO_INCREMENT,
Name varchar(255),
Description varchar(255),
Price double(9,2),
Primary Key(Product_id)
```

);

Method, that adds a record to the table. Problem is with column price. In mysql i defined it: Double(9,2). When I add it like this, everything works fine.

```
public void insertProduct(Product product) {

    this.databaseService.performDML(
            String.format("INSERT INTO product (name,description,price) " +
                            "VALUES ('%s', '%s', '"+product.getPrice()+"')",
                    product.getName(),
                    product.getDescription())
    );
}
```

but when adding looks like this, i have exception: "Data truncated for column 'Price' at row 1"

```
 public void insertProduct(Product product) {
    this.databaseService.performDML(
            String.format("INSERT INTO product (name,description,price) " +
                            "VALUES ('%s', '%s', '%f')",
                    product.getName(),
                    product.getDescription(),
                    product.getPrice())
    );
}
```

Can someone tell me the difference, and how i can add data properly with String.format?

Comment: Use prepared statements instead of string concatenation.

Comment: I'm actually surprised the first one works since the `price` field takes a numerical value and I always thought that table fields declared as numerical data types shouldn't be enclosed in apostrophes ( ' ... ' ). Try it like this: `String.format("INSERT INTO product (name,description,price) VALUES ('%s', '%s', %.3f);", product.getName(), product.getDescription(), product.getPrice()));`. On the same token, I've never seen anyone use the String#format() method to build an SQL statement before. I personally have always used Prepared Statements (in Java). It takes care of the apostrophe game.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the conclusion, use prepared statements instead of building a string yourself for SQL statements.

---

But if you are really wondering about the difference between the two strings... the main difference is that the price gets padding zeros after the point for doubles if you use `String.format()` method.
You could simply print the two strings in console to see the difference.

For example, for the price is 12.345:

> String.format("INSERT INTO product (name,description,price) " + 
> "VALUES ('%s', '%s', '"+product.getPrice()+"')",
> product.getName(),
> product.getDescription())

The first string gets "12.345".

> String.format("INSERT INTO product (name,description,price) " +
> "VALUES ('%s', '%s', '%f')",
> product.getName(),
> product.getDescription(),
> product.getPrice())

The second string gets "12.345000".